# Recommended method to protect /downloader?

Tags: security, magento-connect, downloader

Since Magento uses the **/downloader** as a way to conveniently install programs via *Magento Connect Manager* it is apparent that this is also a security concern since it allows the possibility for bots or people to attempt to learn credentials for the installation.

Checking access logs to my website, I was alarmed at the amount of attempts to the **www.mysite.com/downloader**

As a work around I've gotten into the habit of renaming the downloader directory to **downloader.offline** but occasionally I forget. (Either to rename it back to install a program or after I'm done).

What is the recommended method to protect this link?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just put a .htaccess (or if nginx/whatever a config) into the `downloader` directory with `Disallow from all` in it to forbid any request on the directory.

If you wanted to allow a few IP addresses in (like your own), try something like this in your `.htaccess`

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8
```

Where `1.2.3.4` and `5.6.7.8` are IP addresses you want to let through.

**My prefered way: Just delete `downloader`**

Comment: Would that prevent myself from accessing?

Comment: Sure, no one can access it then. Is Magento connect in this path? Then you need to Allow from <ip> or use authorization

Comment: Or better yet, don't use the downloader at all.

Comment: Of course! Magento connect doesn't allow reliable reproduction of the system's status and using a version control system. I recommend to use modman or better composer!

Comment: Composer FTW - Fabian's dead on here.

Comment: Restricting access to the `/downloader` directory prevents back office orders from being raised (with Sagepay Pro extension at least) and causes an issue with the [Sagepay redirection URL](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes/5006-unable-redirect-vendors-web-site-vendor-failed-provide-redirectionurl) for some reason.

Comment: download is the magento connect directory. If this makes problems this extension seems to be very broken?

Comment: Yes, you're telling me Fabian :/ Wouldn't be the first time we come across absurd code in 3rd party extensions.

Answer (score 17):

Along with @daniel-sloof's recommendation I would say to ditch the Magento Connect installer altogether. I generally add it to `.gitignore` when setting up a new repository.

The reason being, as Fabian points out in his answer comments, that there is no way to ensure the replication of your production environment in source control without committing the packages from Connect. The feature you'll be losing here is the ability to update/upgrade packages from Connect - but if you really need that functionality you can always do it locally on your dev box and commit the results when you're satisfied that they work.

**tl;dr:**

Delete the `/downloader` folder or remove it from your source control.

Comment: Kind of annoying though, not having access to ./mage any more. I assume the `./mage install` CLI command is just a wrapper for Magento Connect.
edit: Actually I can just use `magerun extension:install` :)

Comment: :/ N98-Magerun is also a wrapper for `downloader/mage.php`. I guess you could just copy /downloader to your local dev environment if you need to install something

Comment: For some reason, I only ever find myself running ./mage as a file downloader on my development server anymore. It's only reason for existence on live environments is patch dependencies anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I usually delete the downloader directory, but also found the following directive in the root htaccess helpful:

```
RewriteRule ^downloader/ - [L,R=404]
```

Which will make Apache send a 404 response even if the downloader directory is present.

Comment: I like this method too

Comment: Doesn't work for all downloader requests.  try `www.mysite.com/index.php/myadminurl/index/downloader`

Comment: Although, the method in my other comment isn't really accessing the downloader, it's just a shortcut (longcut?) to the admin login.  Someone would have to know your adminurl for this to work.  if you haven't patched the adminurl disclosure vulnerability, it is likely for someone to obtain it.

Comment: worked for me too. Perfection

Answer (score 5):

what about renaming the downloader folder? In case of need can easily be renamed back to "downloader", doing update and install as needed, and then changing it again. It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf downloader/`

https://www.zdnet.com/article/magento-online-stores-hacked-in-largest-campaign-to-date/

OpenMage LTS also removed it a while ago https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/commit/c02c9ed53b990a7549a89c03346d755aa11e263e

Use OpenMage LTS to be as secure 'as possible' https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/commit/c02c9ed53b990a7549a89c03346d755aa11e263e

To block the downloader application, add the following rule to your nginx.conf file:

```
location ~ ^/downloader/ {
    allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
    deny all;
}
```