# Secure and magento / downloader

Tags: security, downloader

I would secure my / downloader. I wish that no one is accessing this road except me how to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to secure the downloader is removing the folder from PROD to avoid security and code issues. See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/recommended-method-to-protect-downloader) answer for some more info and ideas.