# Magento connect manager in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, downloader

I want to use Magento Connect to install a plugin. I am receiving a 404 page when I try to open it.

Comment: when did you receive the 404 error? when you are going to open installed plugin or when you are opening magento connect manager from system-->magento connect?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your admin/developers did their job and either removed or [protected](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98322/243) the connect manager.

It's

1.) a potential security risk .

2.)And  untested extensions might break your site.

That's why you should not use the connect manager directly on a production site.

Instead download the extension to a development site, test it, then move the code to production. To download it without the connect manager, you can use this tool: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Answer (score 1):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: Good alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

- Change permission of Directory /downloader/ set to 755
- Change permission of file /downloader/index.php set to 644.
- Refresh the cache and delete the previous session.

I hope this will solve your problem.
If problem still persists, please let me know.

Comment: I tried to the above steps. it's not solve.

Comment: Have you tried to access magento connect manager by hitting URL **`http://yourstoreurl/downloader/`**?

Comment: Are you getting same error while accessing by direct URL also?

Comment: yes. same error occur

Comment: Does downloader folder exist in magento root folder? Please compare folder content with fresh copy of magento.

Comment: Also check whether downloader folder contains .htaccess file. If yes, take backup of it and remove. Now check magento connect in the browser.

Comment: Sorry. Again same

Comment: Then it would be better to either go with solution of @babyinmagento, or may be reset file permissions of whole magento.

Comment: How to whole file permission..kindly please tell me

Comment: Please visit http://www.kathirvel.com/magento-setup-file-folder-permissions/ for more information.