# Magento upgrade 1.9.3 to 1.9.4

Tags: magento1.9.3, magento1.9.3.1, magento1.9.0.1

I tried to update my magento 1.9.3 version to magento 1.9.4.1 by replacing the files by magento 1.9.4.1. After that i am getting an 500 internal server error.

How can I resolve this? I am using cPanel to replace the files.

Comment: Can you tell us that is written to the logfiles?

Comment: No log files are printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this is due to file permissions.
From the root of your Magento install run:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;     
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;     
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

If this works, you should try to lower the permissions a little, this are too permissive but will allow you to check if you are on the right path. If it's working please check this [excellent answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/151572/78462) for detailed explanation.

Comment: how can i run these commands from cpanel?

Comment: I am not aware of a simple way of setting permissions recursively through a cPanel.  The easiest way is to run those commands in an SSH console. If that is not possible you can achieve the same result by using an FTP client.  
For example Filezila. In the remote server panel (usually, the right one) **right click** the Magento root folder and select `File Permisions` enter **644** in the **Numeric values**, check **Recurse into subdirectories** and select **apply to files only**, click **OK**  
Again on Magento root set **755** but select **apply to directories only**

Comment: For `var` and `media` select them, enter **777** and apply it to **directories and files**. If you need some visual reference check - https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/change-file-folder-permissions-using-filezilla/ Or if you prefer some other FTP client check how you can set permissions recursively.

Comment: Thank you brother!! It worked