# Magento : Unprotected development files? patch

Tags: patches, magento-1.14

How to apply "Unprotected development files?" patch in magento EE 1.14.2.3.In my mage report it shows Unprotected development files? as medium so i want to apply this.Please explain
I found need to give permissions to dev folder and .htaccess file.How to do it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to delete the `dev` directory from the server and exclude it from your deployment.

Otherwise you have the same options like with the `downloader` directory, as described here: [Recommended method to protect /downloader?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/recommended-method-to-protect-downloader)