# Is it safe to have composer in production?

Tags: magento2, security, composer, server-setup, hosting

Is it safe/ok to have composer in production on a server hosting Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security wise there is **no problem** as long as composer.json, composer.lock and the vendor directory are outside of the document root. This is the case **if you use the recommended setup with `pub` as document root**. Otherwise you should set up your web server such that there is no access to these files (e.g. `Deny from all` in Apache configuration)

#### Why it is problematic if composer files are visible from the outside

- Information disclosure: Attackers can see exact version of all modules and libraries and easily look for known vulnerabilities
- Potential security risks in library files: For example there was one recent exploit in PHPUnit. PHPUnit files were never supposed to be accessible from the web, but if you do not protect `vendor`, they are. Details: https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-9841/

Comment: Fabian, for a Magento installation, under "document root" do you mean the root directory, where the directories "app", "bin", "dev" etc. are located? Thanks!

Comment: It depends. Document root is what the *web server* points to. It can be the Magento root directory that you refer to, but it should be the subdirectory "pub"

Comment: Do you mean that "composer.json" and "composer.lock" should both located in the "pub" directory, or, on the contrary, not?

How do you protect the vendor directory? Thanks!

Comment: On the contrary. You are not supposed to move these files around. This is all about server configuration.

Comment: How do you protect the "vendor" directory?

Comment: @Supersonic as described here for "downloader": https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/16504/243 (except that deleting or renaming is not an option for `vendor`). But again, if your server is set up correctly with `pub` as the document root, you do not need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent directory listings (for security purposes, for example), you should remove the Indexes keyword from every Options directive in your configuration file. Or to prevent them only for a single directory, you can use:

```
<Directory "/">
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: velvetInk , thanks a lot ! It is very useful to know that.