# Someone is accessing my downloader..What's in /downloader/index.php ? How can I disable it since I never plan to use Magento Connect?

Tags: security, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-connect, downloader

I have a few Magento 1.9 sites running on the same VPS server. I noticed today that the load on the server was unusually high. When I went to investigate, I found out someone was accessing my public_html/downloader/index.php of one of the Magento sites and that was taking up about 35% of my CPU. This is definitely NOT intentional as I am the only one with access to all those Magento sites.

*Here are the questions:*

1. What does downloader/index.php suppose to do? Is that a functionality of Magento Connect?
2. **Is there a breach of security I need to worry about?** (*when I suspended that entire account on the server, the same exact thing started happening with another Magento account; when I suspended that one - the load went down to normal*)
3. Since **I never ever plan to use Magento Connect** (things have gone down a really bad path every time I tried to use it in the past) - **can I disable it and HOW?**

Comment: check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16508/20064)

Comment: @Piyush - Thank you  Piyush! You are my hero! ;-)